# Discord Buttons "Interaction Failed": TypeError: MyView.on_button_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button' / 'interaction'

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I have been trying to make buttons bassed off of a list that the user inputs but I keep getting this error that boggles my mind. The error occurs when I press the buttons. The buttons are made but when I press one of the buttons i keep getting the infamous "interaction failed".

Error:
`TypeError: MyView.on_button_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button'`

Code:

```
class MyView(View):
        def __init__(self, options):
                super().__init__()
                self.options = options
                
                for option in options:
                        button = Button(label=option, custom_id=option)
                        button.callback = self.on_button_click  
                        self.add_item(button) 
                        

        async def on_button_click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"You clicked: {button.label}")
```

The reason why this boggles my mind is because when I try and switch the on on_button_click to:`async def on_button_click(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):` I will get the error `TypeError: MyView.on_button_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'interaction'` If you know how to fix this or what might be wrong please let me know. thanks...

I tried switching the foration of the def function to no avail. I also tried adding discord.Interactions and discord.ui.Buttons to the class arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs clearly say that the `Button.callback` function should only take one argument, `interaction`:

```py
class MyView(View):
    def __init__(self, options):
        super().__init__()
        self.options = options
                
        for option in options:
            button = Button(label=option, custom_id=option)
            button.callback = self.on_button_click  
            self.add_item(button) 
                        

    async def on_button_click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        ...
```

However, you cannot access the `Button.label` attribute now, to fix that you can simply create your own custom button:

```py
class MyButton(Button):
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"You clicked {self.label}")


class MyView(View):
    def __init__(self, options):
        super().__init__()

        self.options = options

        for option in options:
            button = MyButton(label=option, custom_id=option)
            self.add_item(button)
```